How to display images saved in Azure Blob storage
I'm working on an app that needs to load images of a web novel which are saved in Azure Storage Accounts as blobs. I enabled anonymous reads to display the image upon request, this works using a web browser or postman. The problem is I'm unable to access an image but rather data that shows as text.
I tried using axios to request as a blob and the data returned is text. I also tried using an arraybuffer like so:
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const response = await axios.get(
    "azure blob link",
    { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }
  );

  res.set('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
  res.send(Buffer.from(response.data, 'binary'));
});

But I am unable to send multiple images this way. Would I need a CDN as users will frequently access these images to read them?

What happens when you put the URL to your image into a web browser?

It displays the image in my web browser.

The Storage Service, by default, will use the MIME type (Content-Type) which was used by the client when uploading the blob. In your case it appears to have been text/plain.
You can either:

Update the blob Content-Type
Using the Azure CLI (install locally or use cloud shell), you can update the content type like so:

az storage blob update \
    --account-name <account_name> \
    --container-name <container_name> \
    --name <blob_name> \
    --content-type "image/jpeg"

Substitute the placeholders and choose the correct image type image/jpeg, image/png, etc.

Specify your expected MIME type
You can try specifying the content-type you're expecting in your request, using the Accept HTTP header.

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const response = await axios.get(
    "azure blob link",
    {
      responseType: 'arraybuffer',
      headers: {
        "Accept": "image/jpeg"
      }
    }
  );
  res.send(Buffer.from(response.data, 'binary'));
});

You can also try using the Accept header in your Postman request.

I tried providing the mime type but I still get the text unless I use res.set().

@21march So, when you use res.set('Content-Type...)`, the client calling your app gets a response with the correct image/jpeg header? If so, what is the problem you're trying to solve? If you browse to your app, you should get an image. The response data itself is still the same, regardless of content-type. If Postman says the response from your app is image/jpeg then a browser shouldn't display text, unless the browser has cached an old response where the header was text/* content type.

I wanted my get route to retrieve all stories and I felt that the method I used would make the process difficult. I appreciate you answering my question none the less. I'm going to move my blobs to my database due to the cost of Azure Storage Accounts. Thank you once again

@21march OK I misunderstood your question. You're having an issue returning multiple images. What you need is a multipart HTTP response. But, you will never get a browser to display a multipart response. And if you sling multiple images in a response as image/jpeg then you've compromised the payload and the browser can't understand it, hence the text displayed. You would need client side script to render multiple images from a single response. Database won't help. Let me know if you want me to post another answer. And if there is a lot of data and requests, Azure Front Door (CDN) would help.
